# Samsung Touchwiz always prompts for default app on startup in Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, default, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I have developed an application for my blind friends which has the default home settings set in the manifest, as below:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This worked fine until they upgraded from a Samsung Galaxy XCover (2.3.6) to a Samsung S3 (4.1.1) last week. Now, after installation, and pressing the home key, a dialog box appears and they get to chose between this app and Samsung Touchwiz and they pick my app and then they press the always button.  However, when they restart the phone and dismiss the lock screen, the dialog box appears again. I have looked in `apps -> settings -> all screen` and I can see that my app is set as default.

Have I missed something?